# Multiple Bindings on WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-rest

I want to host a WCF 4.0 Service in IIS 7.5, and be able to bind to it with `basicHttpBinding` and also RESTfully with `webHttpBinding`.

I need to be able to access it like so:

http://server/wcf/service/method/parameters (REST)

and also like so:

http://server/wcf/service.svc (Basic HTTP)

So far, I have this for my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="SAIF.Services.WCF.Services.CustomerContactService">
        <endpoint address="CustomerContact" behaviorConfiguration="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SAIF.Services.WCF.Contracts.ICustomerContactService" />
        <endpoint address="CustomerContact.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SAIF.Services.WCF.Contracts.ICustomerContactService" />
      </service>
      <service name="SAIF.Services.WCF.Services.OnlineLoginService">
        <endpoint address="OnlineLogin" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SAIF.Services.WCF.Contracts.IOnlineLoginService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="CustomerContact.svc" service="SAIF.Services.WCF.Services.CustomerContactService" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I also have this in my global.asax file for the extension less activation's:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
        Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("CustomerContact", New ServiceHostFactory, GetType(SAIF.Services.WCF.Services.CustomerContactService)))
        Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("OnlineLogin", New ServiceHostFactory, GetType(SAIF.Services.WCF.Services.OnlineLoginService)))
    End Sub
```

I have decorated the service's with this:

And my Service Interface's with the `UriTemplates`

Don't seem to be able to access them both RESTfully and over SOAP.

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: Why does it have to be the same base URL? Why not `http://server/wcf/restservice/method/parameters` and `http://server/wcf/soapservice/service.svc`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - We are going to have 20-25 WCF Services, so I was thinking of that naming convention to make it easy to maintain, but I suppose it could be a little different.

Comment: My suggestion would allow "soapservice" and "restservice" to be separate applications in IIS. "restservice" would be the beginning of a restful URL mapping to routes.

Comment: Which .NET version are you on? Is it .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just decorate your method with both OperationContract and WebGet attributes. Now add the following to system.serviceModel element in your servers web.config

```
    <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
            <!-- 
                Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
                via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
            -->
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
              <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
            </standardEndpoint>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
```

NOTE: Yo
You can remove the json endpoint from the above(as we would achieve a clear URL concept using the new REST Api), And in your global.asax just replace the following:

```
Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("CustomerContactService", New WebServiceHostFactory, typeof(SAIF.Services.WCF.Services.CustomerContactService)));
```

Now once you do the above you should be able to access the same service via SOAP and REST and the URLs would be as follows:

SOAP --> http://localhost/virtualdirectoryname/CustomerContactService.svc

REST --> http://localhost/virtualdirectoryname/CustomerContactService/method/parameters

Now browse to your service in IE and you should see the SOAP server when you browse to .svc file and when you browse to the rest URL you should see either xml coming up in the browser of a file should be downloaded that contains the response in json format.